# How to modify csv database in flask so that data is not overwritten?

Tags: csv, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm just making a form to report an error, and when the user writes an error to the form and sends it, the data is written to the csv file, but when he writes another one, the previous one is deleted and overwritten with the current one to do so so that the data is stored below and didn't they rewrite the previous ones?

And one more thing, the form is made in flask.

Flask code:

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=["GET","POST"])
def get_contact():
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name =  request.form["name"]
        email = request.form["email"]
        message = request.form["message"]
        res = pd.DataFrame({'name':name, 'email':email, 'message':message}, index=[0])
        res.to_csv('./contactDatabase.csv')
        return redirect(url_for("rgb"))
    else:
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

After submitting the form, the data is stored in this way:

[CSV Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkcx6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new dataframe everytime the form is submitted and writing it over the existing csv. To append it, include mode='a'. The default is 'w'.

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=["GET","POST"])
def get_contact():
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name =  request.form["name"]
        email = request.form["email"]
        message = request.form["message"]
        res = pd.DataFrame({'name':name, 'email':email, 'message':message}, index=[])
        res.to_csv('./contactDatabase.csv', mode='a', header =False)
        return redirect(url_for("rgb"))
    else:
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```